# Render of a 3D model with corresponding XYZ coordinates of each pixel directly

Tags: python, rendering, nvidia, open3d

I have a 3D model (an `.obj` file with materials) that I would like to render a specific view of given a camera pose. I then need the corresponding model XYZ coordinates for each rendered pixel on the model.

Currently I use `open3d.visualization.rendering` in Python to render the scene and get a depth image, which I then use to back calculate the XYZ coords. Is there a way to directly get the 3D position of the "ray" impact?

Furthermore, is they a way to use something like [NVIDIA's warp](https://github.com/NVIDIA/warp/blob/main/examples/example_raycast.py) to do this faster on my GPU?